# Ecommerce Analytics goals - good candidates

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

Aside from the obvious checkout goal - what would be good candidates for Google Analytics goals on an e-commerce site.

I am struggling of think of any.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it would depend a lot on your ecommerce site features. But here comes a couple that pop from my mind:

- Newsletter subscriptions
- New signups
- Product review written
- Product comment added
- Contact Form Submitted
- Product Rated
- Product added to Shopping Cart
- Using a sharing tool (tweetthis, sharethis, etc)
- Using a Compare Tool
- Arriving a certain step on the checkout process

This last one is intersting. Of course if you setup a goal on the checkout and have a nice funnel viz, you can get that for free. But assigning a goal to a particular step that you know a lot of users leave the funnel, can help you segment and analyze this guys. Just segment by users who completed that goal, and did not complete the checkout goal.